# wordpress plugin or jquery for menu to pop upwards on click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

1. I have gone through the google for my menu.But, all in vain.
2. I am trying to get a menu which on click pop upwards.
3. Also, any jquery would be appriciated.

Comment: What is your code? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I am not very good in jquery.So, simply tried for plugins.But, won't get any similar one.

Comment: What class,id does your menu has, whats your pop upwards?

Comment: have you checked this: http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/NMs4Z/2/

Comment: Possible to provide me a plugin.